# How do you get the texture coordinate hit by the mouse on a UI Raw Image in Unity?

Tags: unity, gui

It seems raycast hit does not work for UI... is it possible to get the .textureCoord of a point hit by the mouse on a UI raw image? (raw image provided by a render camera elsewhere far far away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RectTransformUtility` has a [helper method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html) for finding the position of a screen point inside any`RectTransform`'s bounding rectangle:

```
var rt = (RectTransform)rawImage.transform;

bool inside = RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
    (RectTransform)rawImage.trasnform,
    Input.mousePosition,
    camera,
    out Vector2 pointInRect
);
```

Then you can just remap these coordinates from the local rectangle of the `RawImage` object into the UV space of the texture it's displaying:

```
if (inside) {
    Vector2 textureCoord = pointInRect - rt.rect.min;
    textureCoord.x *= rawImage.uvRect.width / rt.rect.width;
    textureCoord.y *= rawImage.uvRect.height / rt.rect.height;
    textureCoord += rawImage.uvRect.min;
}
```

Note that if your UI is in "Screen Space - Overlay mode", then the `camera` argument should be `null`.

If your texture coordinates are upside-down, you may need to set

```
trextureCoord.y = rt.rect.height - textureCoord.y;
```

before the scaling step.

Comment: Okay, this surely beats my GraphicCaster attempt - thank you!!!